# Get location from JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, jsonp

I am working now in a phonegap android application, I need the user's current address, so that i have used this 
[JSON api](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=26.9008773,75.7403539&sensor=true).

This is my code to get data for location updates from JSON api

```
$.ajax('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=26.9008773,75.7403539&sensor=true', {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        timeout: 3000,
        data: {
            _method: 'GET'
        },
        success: function (data,status) {
            if (data._status != 200) {
                console.log('received error', data._status);
                // handle error
            }else{
                console.log('received data', data);
                // do something useful with the data
                }
            },
        error: function(data,status) {
                var myObject = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log("Data Returned is " + myObject);
                console.log("Status is " + status);
                alert('error');
            },
        complete: function(data, status) {
                alert('complete');
            }
    });
```

Every time it goes on error section , then the complete section, never goes into the success part.
the console output is :

```
    12-10 11:11:34.393: I/Web Console(10620): Data Returned is {"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"} at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:263
    12-10 11:11:34.393: I/Web Console(10620): Status is error at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:264
```

Can anyone tell me, where exactly the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the default security policy in PhoneGap is to block all network access. You need to whitelist `http://maps.googleapis.com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ajax_call ='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=26.9008773,75.7403539&sensor=true';
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: ajax_call,
       cache:false,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(response){
                $.each(response.results, function(key, value) {                       
                            //alert(value.formatted_address);   
                             console.log(value.formatted_address);                                       
                });
       }
    }).done(function() {

    })
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but not resolved - same as earliar

Answer (score 0):

The api you request does not support jsonp,  the final request will like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?callback=jQuery18309743240959942341_1386656119920&latlng=26.9008773,75.7403539&sensor=true&_method=GET&_=1386656120107
```

with the callback param, but the output is still json, not javsscript file like

```
jQuery18309743240959942341_1386656119920(jsonDataHere...)
```

Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse, it request url like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d40.714224&2d-73.96145200000001&7sUS&9sen&callback=_xdc_._4cni6z&token=46423
```

And the output is:

```
_xdc_._4cni6z && _xdc_._4cni6z( { ....
```

That's jsonp.

Comment: I don't want to display location on map, i just want to display address text in alert, DO I need to get tocken for it also...

Comment: The key part is geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) { //now you get the results